# How to add and remove class when user clicks and hover a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, removeclass

I have a list of  menu items  and i want to add same class  when a user clicks on any *li* **or** add class on hover *li*.

I have a menu items like following:

```
$('#menu li').click(function() {
    $('#menu li').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$("#menu li").hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }, 
                function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/173/

the issue is if user clicks 'li' the class added to  the li , when mouse over I need to remove the class added Due to the previous  user click or again added the  active iems.

Comment: for hover you can directly use :hover not sure what you asking for is this http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/175/ ?

Comment: @hover class i need to display the bootstrap icon ...

Comment: @kukkuz : i modified

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it

```
$('#menu li').click(function() {
    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$("#menu li").hover(function () {
    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/176/)

But still your requirement is not clear as much to draw on jsFiddle so please have a look and let us know what exactly you required within this.

## Edited

I have just added to different classes one for click active and another for hover active so try hover and then click you will find different between both functions

```
<script>
$('#menu li').click(function() {
    $('#menu li').removeClass('clickactive hoveractive');
    $(this).addClass('clickactive');
});

$("#menu li").hover(function () {
    $('#menu li').removeClass('hoveractive clickactive');
    $(this).addClass('hoveractive');
});
</script>

<style>
.hoveractive{
    color:red;
}  
.clickactive{
    color: green;
}
</style>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/177/) is an updated jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfun() {
    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
$('#menu li').click(myfun);
$("#menu li").hover(myfun);
```

same as above one but dont maintain duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

This will work for u..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#menu li').click(function() {
  $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$("#menu li").hover(function(){
   $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
   }, function(){
   $(this).addClass('active');
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the class on click and hover is not a good idea.
It looks like your trying to have funcitonality for mobile and desktop.

Try checking the doc width and running code depending on screen size.

```
var docWidth = $(window).width();

if (docWidth <= 767) {
    $('#menu li').click(function() {
        $('#menu li').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}
else {
    $('#menu li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {//note add callback function
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not realize this but your `$('#menu li').click` event is actually called and the class does change but as you hover out of the `li` the `mouseout` effect takes place and the `active` class is removed. My suggestion is to make a new class `active1` which is same as `active` when you click on an li the color does change only this time with `mouseout` effect won't remove active class from it as it was not there in the first place.

```
           $("#menu li").click(function () {
                $("#menu li").not(this).removeClass("active1");
                $(this).addClass("active1");
            });

            .active1{
                color: red;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hover but the `active` class still there you can use this one and you can reduce script function as well.

```js
$('#menu li').click(function() {
    $('#menu li').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li{

    color: blue;
}
li:hover{

    color: red;
}
.active{
    color:red;
    //background-image:'';
  }  
.active{
    color:red;
    //background-image:'';
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
<li>one</li>
<li>one</li>
<li>one</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another css class named "clicked" and add that class on click and active on hover.

```
$('#menu li').click(function() {
    //alert("chala BC");
$('#menu li').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
$(this).addClass('clicked');
});

$("#menu li").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }, 
            function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
```